# Automatically make links to URLs

Tags: html

Basically at the moment I have:

```
http://link.com - plain text
```

I would like:

```
<a href="http://link.com">http://link.com</a>
```

Is it possible to automatically add '`a href`'?

If so how should I go about doing it?

Comment: Do you have server-side programming (PHP, JSP or ASP.NET) or do you want this done in JavaScript?

Comment: What language? During display, during save to database?

Comment: This should give you an idea of how to start thinking about it:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001181.html

Comment: Daniel - I would prefer it in Javascript to be honest, as i understand it abit more than PHP - what would be the best solution?

Darryl - During display it will be HTML. I won't want it saving to a database.

I guess would it be easy to tell Javascript each time there is a line which starts with http:// in a certain <div> to add a 'a href' to it?

Many thanks,

Dave

Comment: jeffamaphone - Many thanks, will look at that now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could parse your text on load with javascript. By using the appropriate regular expression, just replace each link with the anchored link version.

```
text.replace(**link regular expression**, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
```

**Note**: The syntax is probably not right, but you get the idea.